# Mvc4 RTM validation throwing an error

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, restsharp

Has something changed with the rtm bits regarding the validation of models.

I have a simple viewmodel that looks like

```
    public class ProductViewModel
    { 
    [Required]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    }
```

(I just added the DataMember(IsRequired = true) as the error message I get says to use it to fix the problem. However no joy)

Within my controller the model state is telling me model is valid however when I try passing the model to my api using RestSharp I get the following error.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Property 'ProductTypeId' on type 'Mine.Model.Model' is invalid. Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Validation.Validators.ErrorModelValidator.Validate(ModelMetadata metadata, Object container)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ShallowValidate(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object model)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass36`1.<>c__DisplayClass38.<Then>b__35()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass49.<ToAsyncVoidTask>b__48()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

I wasnt having this problem with the rc bits but then I have only started to use the restsharp libary with the rtm bits.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to adding [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] to the property, you'll also need to ensure that the attribute [DataContract] is applied at the class level.

Comment: I have a single model class that both my UI mvc project and the WebApi project consume. So adding [DataContract] wont cause any problems?

Comment: I don't believe so. DataContract affects serialization, not MVC model binding.

Comment: Adding DataContract gets me to the controller within the api however all of the parameters are not sent. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Unfortunately, once you add [DataContract] you'll need to put [DataMember] on every field you want serialized. I had the same issue here - had to modify all of my entities. If "DataContract" is left off, .NET will infer the data contract using publicly visible types. Once you put DataContract on a class, you're telling .NET you want to customize serialization. You need to put DataMember on each value you want serialized, and then customize it through the properties on the DataMember attribute - ie/ IsRequired

Answer (score 0):

The data entry DataContract is being consumed by the UI to create the data entry form and the back-end whenever the form is posted.  So, is it safe to say that [DataMember(IsRequired = true)] is needed for the back-end and [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Product type is required)] is needed for form validation so you can access the error message?

I'm not sure why we have to do both.  Why can't we have a single attribute to be used by front-end and server side?